# Solving $\lim_{(h \rightarrow 0)} \frac{\sqrt{1+h}-1}{\tan(h)}$ without using l'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus

I need to find the limit to the following:

$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sqrt{1+h}-1}{\tan(h)}$$

and I actually did find it quite easily using l'Hospital's rule.

However we haven't gone through that in the course yet, is there a different approach you can take in solving this problem?

Comment: Are you sure the numerator shouldn't be $\sqrt{1+h}-1$?

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that I missed out on the -1.

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you for the foresight

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Hint:

$$\begin{align}\frac{\sqrt{1+h}-1}{\tan(h)}&=\frac{\sqrt{1+h}-1}h\frac{\sqrt{1+h}+1}{\sqrt{1+h}+1}\frac h{\sin(h)}\cos(h)\\&=\frac1{\sqrt{1+h}+1}\frac h{\sin(h)}\cos(h)\end{align}$$

Comment: Small additional detail: what you wrote doesn't rule out the limit being $\infty$ (here, it's not even diverging to $\infty$)

Comment: @ClementC. I kind of shrug off limits being $\pm\infty$, but sure, I suppose so.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I completely missed that it's supposed to be sqrt(1+h)-1/tan(h)

Comment: @ejbs No problem, re-updated

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt
In the middle step I can see that you've used tan(h) = sin(h)/cos(h), did you then also multiply with h/h and then finally multiply with sqrt(1+h)+1/sqrt(1+h)+1 ?

Nice, so it can be done with 'normal' re-writes.

And then you used (x+y)(x-y) = x^2-y^2 it looks like. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @ejbs  Yup, you caught all of the steps!  :D

Answer (score 1):

*Equivalents:*

$\sqrt{1+h}-1\sim_0\frac12 h$, $\;\tan h\sim_0 h$, so 
$$\frac{\sqrt{1+h}-1}{\tan h}\sim_0\frac{\frac12 h}{h}=\frac12.$$